# How to use a tiles variable in JSP page

Tags: jsp, struts, tiles

I have a variable defined in Tiles. I want to use that variable in JSP page.

I tried using

```
<tiles:put name="title"><tiles:getAsString name="title" /></tiles:put>
```

but I am not able to assign the value in some `var` in JSP page. Depending on the variable I need to implement some logic in JSP page. How to do this?

Comment: *i tried using <tiles:put name="title"><tiles:getAsString name="title" /></tiles:put>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use some definition in `tiles-defs.xml`:

```
<definition name="title.tile" >
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Some Title" type="string"/>
</definition>
```

Now in the tile you can use

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<html>
<head>
<title><tiles:getAsString name="title" /></title>
```